# Daylight Saving Time and UTC-to-local time conversions with WinAPIs

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, dst

I'm trying to see if WindAPIs that convert from local to UTC time and vice versa are Daylight Saving Time accurate. For instance, let's take [LocalFileTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724490%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. Its description states:

> LocalFileTimeToFileTime uses the current settings for the time zone
>   and daylight saving time. Therefore, if it is daylight saving time,
>   this function will take daylight saving time into account, even if the
>   time you are converting is in standard time.

So I'm testing it with this code:

```
//Say, if DST change takes place on Mar-8-2015 at 2:00:00 AM
//when the clock is set 1 hr forward

//Let's check the difference between two times:
SYSTEMTIME st1_local = {2015, 3, 0, 8, 1, 30, 0, 0};    //Mar-8-2015 1:30:00 AM
SYSTEMTIME st2_local = {2015, 3, 0, 8, 3, 30, 0, 0};    //Mar-8-2015 3:30:00 AM

//Convert to file-time format
FILETIME ft1_local, ft2_local;
VERIFY(::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st1_local, &ft1_local));
VERIFY(::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st2_local, &ft2_local));

//Then convert from local to UTC time
FILETIME ft1_utc, ft2_utc;
VERIFY(::LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&ft1_local, &ft1_utc));
VERIFY(::LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&ft2_local, &ft2_utc));

//Get the difference
LONGLONG iiDiff100ns = (((LONGLONG)ft2_utc.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ft2_utc.dwLowDateTime) -
    (((LONGLONG)ft1_utc.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ft1_utc.dwLowDateTime);

//Convert from 100ns to seconds
LONGLONG iiDiffSecs = iiDiff100ns / 10000000LL;

//I would expect 1 hr
ASSERT(iiDiffSecs == 3600); //But I get 7200, which is 2 hrs!
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Paul's answer is spot on, but you might also consider using the date and time API of the [Boost C++ Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Comment: @MattJohnson: Yes, it works. Still, apart from the C implementation, what is the issue with the `LocalFileTimeToFileTime` API itself -- does it really use the DST adjustment for the time "now" that it was called at?

Comment: @ahmd0: yes, as the documentation says.

Answer (score 6):

`SystemTimeToFileTime()` interprets its first argument as a UTC time (which has no concept of DST), so your `ft1_local` and `ft2_local` objects will always be two hours apart since you're changing the data format, but not the actual point in time. `LocalFileTimeToFileTime()` will then apply the same offset to whatever you pass to it, so `ft1_utc` and `ft2_utc` will always end up two hours apart, also.

As the documentation says, "`LocalFileTimeToFileTime` **uses the current settings** for the time zone and daylight saving time" (emphasis mine), so if at the current time you're four hours behind UTC, for instance, it'll just deduct four hours from whatever time you pass to it, regardless of whether that time originally represented some time at the other side of DST.

EDIT: Per the comments, here's how you'd get the seconds difference between two local times in standard C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm start_time;
    start_time.tm_year = 115;
    start_time.tm_mon = 2;
    start_time.tm_mday = 8;
    start_time.tm_hour = 1;
    start_time.tm_min = 30;
    start_time.tm_sec = 0;
    start_time.tm_isdst = -1;

    struct tm end_time;
    end_time.tm_year = 115;
    end_time.tm_mon = 2;
    end_time.tm_mday = 8;
    end_time.tm_hour = 3;
    end_time.tm_min = 30;
    end_time.tm_sec = 0;
    end_time.tm_isdst = -1;

    time_t start_tm = mktime(&start_time);
    time_t end_tm = mktime(&end_time);

    if ( start_tm == -1 || end_tm == -1 ) {
        fputs("Couldn't get local time.", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double seconds_diff = difftime(end_tm, start_tm);
    printf("There are %.1f seconds difference.\n", seconds_diff);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@thoth:~/src$ ./difftime
There are 3600.0 seconds difference.
paul@thoth:~/src$
```

as you're expecting.

Note that, with `struct tm`:

- `tm_year` is expressed in years since 1900, so to get 2015 we write 115
- `tm_mon` is in the range 0 though 11, so March is 2, not 3.
- The other time members are as you'd expect
- When `tm_isdst` is set to `-1`, `mktime()` will attempt to find out for itself whether DST was in effect at the local time we supplied, which is what we want it to do, here.

Comment: SystemTimeToFileTime **does not** interpret its first argument as UTC time. It converts it as-is, or in other words `1:30 AM` becomes `1:30 AM`. You can check that by manually converting the FILETIME value into human readable format. It is expressed as `100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601`

Comment: How do you explain this from the documentation of the first argument, then: "A pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure that contains the system time to be converted from UTC to file time format."

Comment: How I'd explain it? Messed up Microsoft documentation :)

Comment: I like your second argument though, about `uses the current settings`. It seems like `LocalFileTimeToFileTime` does indeed take the current DST settings and applies it without any regard to the date being converted. Wow, that's bad. How'd you adjust my method of finding out the time difference between two dates then?

Comment: The `FILETIME` structure contains intervals since January 1, 1601 UTC, so if `1:30AM` always becomes `1:30AM`, this demonstrates that `SystemTimeToFileTime()` interprets its first argument as UTC, it doesn't refute that point.

Comment: I'd convert your local times to UTC, and then do what you did.

Comment: Paul, if it doesn't make any conversions then it doesn't matter what time zone the date is expressed in -- UTC, your time, my time, Mars time.

Comment: So how'd you convert it from a local time to UTC?

Comment: @ahmd0: It makes a difference if you are wanting it to treat one of those times as being DST, and the other as not, because it will never do this.

Comment: OK, Paul, many people don't get this UTC/local thing right. So going back to your previous point -- how'd you convert a local time to UTC -- can you show me?

Comment: @ahmd0: I'd use the standard C functions, such as `mktime()` and `gmtime()`. `mktime()` will take a broken down local time and convert it to a `time_t` value, and `gmtime()` will take that `time_t` value and convert it to a broken down UTC time for you.

Comment: @ahmd0: It would be easier still to avoid Win32 altogether, and just call `mktime()` on your two local dates, and then `difftime()` on the two resulting `time_t` values to get the difference in seconds.

Comment: I haven't been using C for a while. How do you do `mktime` on an absolute date, i.e. `Mar-8-2015 1:30:00 AM`? Or in other words how do I convert it to `time_t`?

Comment: Given that daylight-savings-time rules keep changing, I wouldn't recommending depending on `mktime` being accurate.  It is probably better to stick to UTC times if at all possible.

Comment: Nice answer! I think the crux of this problem is in the [remarks statement of the MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724490.aspx).  That really makes `LocalFileTimeToFileTime` unreliable IMHO.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The obvious problem is that standard C doesn't give you any direct way to actually get a UTC time, other than for the current time, or via a `time_t` which is returned by `mktime()` and friends. It's [possible to do it in a very unsatisfactory way](https://github.com/paulgriffiths/utctime). On the other hand, if you go back far enough, you get whole days being left out of calendars, so there are bigger problems dealing with time.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: well, it depends on the scenario, but in many cases, the current time is all you need.  That is, if you're comparing what the "current time" was at some particular point in the past (the timestamp for a log entry, for example, or the time some event occurred) with the "current time" now, or at a different particular point, then the best solution is probably to just make sure that you record everything in UTC.  Similarly, if you're asking the user to enter a time in the past or future, ask for it in UTC - if you can get away with it!

Comment: I'm not sure whether Microsoft have ever updated the Visual Studio runtimes to change the daylight-savings-time logic.  So I suspect that mktime() with `tm_isdst=-1` will be accurate only if the version of Visual Studio you're using was released after the most recent DST changes (in whatever part of the world you're targeting).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I don't think they'd need to change the runtime as long as they have an up-to-date timezone database somewhere on the system, since the function will likely just query that, but yes, Microsoft's reputation for respecting C is not exactly legendary!

Comment: @HarryJohnston: And if you're just recording the current time, you're likely to save a `time_t` value anyway, which is independent of time zones or DST or anything like that, at least in all modern systems I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a timezone database exposed to applications on Windows, if I get a chance I'll have a look at the code for `mktime` on Monday and see what it's doing.  Though even if there is a database, I'm betting it only describes one set of rules - so if you're dealing with times from before those rules came into effect, you're still sunk.  I rather suspect Linux doesn't carry a timezone history either, though I might be wrong. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm not sure about Windows, either, but you're right in that the Linux database only contains the timezone entries for right now, so even if the current entries are correct, if you go back far enough until one changes, it'll start getting the local datetimes "wrong", or at least not lining up with what would have been reported at the time. On the other hand, since nobody living in, say, 52 BCE would have called the year "52 BCE" at the time, arguably this kind of historical revisionism is inherent in the calendar anyway! :)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Thanks, C has a good solution. Although I would probably go with Microsoft's `_mktime64` since I'm asking it for Windows. Otherwise the dates will be cut off at 2038.

Comment: @ahmd0: Looks like you're right, Microsoft has a pretty poor implementation of `mktime()`. @HarryJohnston According to Microsoft's documentation, "The C run-time library assumes the United States’s rules for implementing the calculation of Daylight Saving Time". You can always count on them.

Comment: So if you're not in the US, it doesn't work at all?  Lovely! :-)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Hold on, what!? Can you explain your last statement about the US rules. If that's the case this answer is not a solution.

Comment: @ahmd0: My answer is a C answer. I am not responsible for Microsoft having a crappy C implementation. I guess technically Microsoft's implementation could be compliant if `mktime()` returns `-1` and just fails when run in a locale where the DST rules are not the same as those in the US, and the code in my answer handles just such an eventuality.

Comment: Wow. I didn't think it would be such a big deal. I guess I'll have to keep looking...

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I'm not sure if my WinAPI method does it or not. It seems to work for me. Can you check?

Comment: @ahmd0: It's too Microsoft-y for me to check, I don't currently have a Windows machine with a compiler that'll run it. Just come up with a few test cases, from around the world, between times where you know the DST rules are different, and see if it gives the right results. If it does, you're probably good.

Answer (score 2):

In despite of all the beauty of [Paul Griffiths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23304851/670017)' solution, I can't use it due to an apparent locale limitation. (C is obviously showing its age.) So I had to go with a pure WinAPI approach. Next is what I came up with. Correct me if I'm wrong (especially people with access to time zones other than the US one that Microsoft's `mktime` seems to be favoring):

```
SYSTEMTIME st1 = {2015, 3, 0, 8, 1, 30, 0, 0};    //Mar-8-2015 1:30:00 AM
SYSTEMTIME st2 = {2015, 3, 0, 8, 3, 30, 0, 0};    //Mar-8-2015 3:30:00 AM

LONGLONG iiDiffNs;
if(GetLocalDateTimeDifference(&st1, &st2, &iiDiffNs))
{
    _tprintf(L"Difference is %.02f sec\n", (double)iiDiffNs / 1000.0);
}
else
{
    _tprintf(L"ERROR (%d) calculating the difference.\n", ::GetLastError());
}
```

Then this is the actual implementation. One important aspect to note here is that the method below may not work reliably on Windows XP due to the lack of APIs to retrieve time zone info for a specific year.

Some declarations first:

```
enum DST_STATUS{
    DST_ERROR = TIME_ZONE_ID_INVALID,           //Error
    DST_NONE = TIME_ZONE_ID_UNKNOWN,            //Daylight Saving Time is NOT observed
    DST_OFF = TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD,            //Daylight Saving Time is observed, but the system is currently not on it
    DST_ON = TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT,             //Daylight Saving Time is observed, and the system is currently on it
};

#define FILETIME_TO_100NS(f) (((LONGLONG)f.dwHighDateTime << 32) | f.dwLowDateTime)

BOOL GetLocalDateTimeDifference(SYSTEMTIME* pStBegin_Local, SYSTEMTIME* pStEnd_Local, LONGLONG* pOutDiffMs = NULL);
BOOL ConvertLocalTimeToUTCTime(SYSTEMTIME* pSt_Local, SYSTEMTIME* pOutSt_UTC = NULL);
DST_STATUS GetDSTInfoForYear(USHORT uYear, TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION* pTZI = NULL);
```

And the implementation:

```
BOOL GetLocalDateTimeDifference(SYSTEMTIME* pStBegin_Local, SYSTEMTIME* pStEnd_Local, LONGLONG* pOutDiffMs)
{
    //Calculate difference between two local dates considering DST adjustments between them
    //INFO: May not work correctly on Windows XP for a year other than the current year!
    //'pStBegin_Local' = local date/time to start from
    //'pStEnd_Local' = local date/time to end with
    //'pOutDiffMs' = if not NULL, receives the difference in milliseconds (if success)
    //RETURN:
    //      = TRUE if success
    //      = FALSE if error (check GetLastError() for info)
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;
    LONGLONG iiDiffMs = 0;
    int nOSError = NO_ERROR;

    if(pStBegin_Local &&
        pStEnd_Local)
    {
        //Convert both dates to UTC
        SYSTEMTIME stBeginUTC;
        if(ConvertLocalTimeToUTCTime(pStBegin_Local, &stBeginUTC))
        {
            SYSTEMTIME stEndUTC;
            if(ConvertLocalTimeToUTCTime(pStEnd_Local, &stEndUTC))
            {
                //Then convert into a more manageable format: FILETIME
                //It will represent number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 for each date
                FILETIME ftBeginUTC;
                if(::SystemTimeToFileTime(&stBeginUTC, &ftBeginUTC))
                {
                    FILETIME ftEndUTC;
                    if(::SystemTimeToFileTime(&stEndUTC, &ftEndUTC))
                    {
                        //Now get the difference in ms
                        //Convert from 100-ns intervals = 10^7, where ms = 10^3
                        iiDiffMs = (FILETIME_TO_100NS(ftEndUTC) - FILETIME_TO_100NS(ftBeginUTC)) / 10000LL;

                        //Done
                        bRes = TRUE;
                    }
                    else
                        nOSError = ::GetLastError();
                }
                else
                    nOSError = ::GetLastError();
            }
            else
                nOSError = ::GetLastError();
        }
        else
            nOSError = ::GetLastError();
    }
    else
        nOSError = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    if(pOutDiffMs)
        *pOutDiffMs = iiDiffMs;

    ::SetLastError(nOSError);
    return bRes;
}

BOOL ConvertLocalTimeToUTCTime(SYSTEMTIME* pSt_Local, SYSTEMTIME* pOutSt_UTC)
{
    //Convert local date/time from 'pSt_Local'
    //'pOutSt_UTC' = if not NULL, receives converted UTC time
    //RETURN:
    //      = TRUE if success
    //      = FALSE if error (check GetLastError() for info)
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;
    SYSTEMTIME stUTC = {0};
    int nOSError = NO_ERROR;

    if(pSt_Local)
    {
        //First get time zone info
        TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzi;
        if(GetDSTInfoForYear(pSt_Local->wYear, &tzi) != DST_ERROR)
        {
            if(::TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(&tzi, pSt_Local, &stUTC))
            {
                //Done
                bRes = TRUE;
            }
            else
                nOSError = ::GetLastError();
        }
        else
            nOSError = ::GetLastError();
    }
    else
        nOSError = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    if(pOutSt_UTC)
        *pOutSt_UTC = stUTC;

    ::SetLastError(nOSError);
    return bRes;
}

DST_STATUS GetDSTInfoForYear(USHORT uYear, TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION* pTZI)
{
    //Get DST info for specific 'uYear'
    //INFO: Year is not used on the OS prior to Vista SP1
    //'pTZI' = if not NULL, will receive the DST data currently set for the time zone for the year
    //RETURN:
    //      = Current DST status, or an error
    //        If error (check GetLastError() for info)
    DST_STATUS tzStat = DST_ERROR;
    int nOSError = NO_ERROR;

    //Define newer APIs
    DWORD (WINAPI *pfnGetDynamicTimeZoneInformation)(PDYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION);
    BOOL (WINAPI *pfnGetTimeZoneInformationForYear)(USHORT, PDYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, LPTIME_ZONE_INFORMATION);

    //Load APIs dynamically (in case of Windows XP)
    HMODULE hKernel32 = ::GetModuleHandle(L"Kernel32.dll");
    ASSERT(hKernel32);
    (FARPROC&)pfnGetDynamicTimeZoneInformation = ::GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation");
    (FARPROC&)pfnGetTimeZoneInformationForYear = ::GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "GetTimeZoneInformationForYear");

    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzi = {0};

    //Use newer API if possible
    if(pfnGetDynamicTimeZoneInformation &&
        pfnGetTimeZoneInformationForYear)
    {
        //Use new API for dynamic time zone
        DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION dtzi = {0};
        tzStat = (DST_STATUS)pfnGetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(&dtzi);
        if(tzStat == DST_ERROR)
        {
            //Failed -- try old method
            goto lbl_fallback_method;
        }

        //Get TZ info for a year
        if(!pfnGetTimeZoneInformationForYear(uYear, &dtzi, &tzi))
        {
            //Failed -- try old method
            goto lbl_fallback_method;
        }
    }
    else
    {
lbl_fallback_method:
        //Older API (also used as a fall-back method)
        tzStat = (DST_STATUS)GetTimeZoneInformation(&tzi);
        if(tzStat == DST_ERROR)
            nOSError = ::GetLastError();
        else
            nOSError = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    }

    if(pTZI)
    {
        *pTZI = tzi;
    }

    ::SetLastError(nOSError);
    return tzStat;
}
```

Comment: No need to call GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation().  Just pass NULL to the second parameter of GetTimeZoneInformationForYear().